# Письмо от гугл с требованием добавить политики конфиденциальности

Tags: android, google-play

Добрый день, вопрос про файл с политикой конфиденциальности, можно ли его например выложить на гугл диск и открыть доступ всем? И обязательно ли в приложении как то прописывать его или просто в консоли разработчика разместить ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

Надо размещать на отдельном сайте и отсылать гуглу ссылку на данную страницу , и в приложение при первом запуске требовать пользователя подтвердить это соглашение прежде чем пользоваться приложением.

Comment: На чём основана эта информация?

Comment: Вот на счет второго вашего пункта есть сомнения, нигде почти в приложениях этого не встречал.

Comment: @DenisZharikov ну последующих версиях можно убрать , а что бы гугл пропустил можно сделать

Comment: @alexolut Да интересно было когда 1 приложение заливал , читал везде по немногу , все по разному делают ...

Answer (score 0):

Я оставлял в описании приложения ссылку на свой сайт на страницу с политикой конфиденциальности. И все.
Google этим был удовлетворен и ничего больше не потребовал.

Comment: А если нет сайта, можно на гугл диске разместить pdf файл?